# How do I access variables from other functions?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to access variables from other functions. But when I try to make my variables public or static that are in a function, error pops up everywhere(especially public). Here's my code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string f = textBox1.Text;
        label6.Text = f;
        label9.Text = f;
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string n = textBox2.Text;
        label14.Text = n;
    }

    private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can access f or n in textBox6 method?

Comment: Which variable of which function you want to access where? Functions can not have variables with access modifiers such as public.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare `Public`/`Private` variables inside a method/function. Rather the right place is to place public variables is on class level. So, what you can do is :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
 public string Mystring;
}
```

And use this variable from/to anywhere.

But if you are still not satisfied with this and want to keep your variables inside a method/function, you can do one of the followings :

**If method/function is not an event of any control**

If you have a method that is not an eventhandler(or event listener) rather a simple method, you can easily create parameters on method-level :

```
  public Mymethod(string MyString)
  {
  }
```

**If method is indeed an event**

You see, there's always a way or another. Even if you have an event listener, it is not that hard to achieve what you want. Create a method, add required parameters and call it from inside the event :

```
 public void Myvars(string abc, int def)
 {
 ///do additional work if require
 }

 private void Btn1_Click()
 {
  Myvars("text", 1234);
 }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I suggest you follow standard C# conventions when creating example code. Particularly your variable naming and capitalization.

Comment: @mason , roger that